# Notation of Matrix and Coordination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was confused by the notation of the following question

> Let $E = I_5(R_2\leftarrow R_2+4R_3)$, then $E^{-1}=I_5(C_p\leftarrow C_p+\alpha C_q)$, what are the values of $p,q,\alpha$?

I know that the transition matrix of the coordination can be represent as follow..

> $[I]^{\beta}_\gamma$ is the same as $I_{\gamma \rightarrow \beta}$, where $\beta,\gamma$ are the basis of $V, V'$, $T:V \rightarrow V'$

But I have no idea what this notation is...

Comment: This kind of operation is called an elementary row operation. The way to remember the inverse of such is- *swap and negate*. By that I mean if $R_2$ gets changed by $4$ of $R_3$ (since it gets itself plus $4$ of the other), then the inverse is the swap and negate version of that; swap indices $2$ and $3$ and negate the scalar $4$ and apply that to columns for the operation of $C_3$ gets changed by $-4$ of $C_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says if $E$ is obtained by replacing the second row of the $5\times5$ identity matrix $I_5$ by the sum of the second row and four times the thrid row of $I_5$, then $E^{-1}$ is equal to the matrix obtained by replacing the $p$-th column of $I_5$ by the sum of the $p$-th column and $\alpha$ times the $q$-th column of $I_5$. Now you are asked to determine the indices $p,q$ and the multiplier $\alpha$.